# Adding/Removing Strings in an ArrayList<String> by Checkbox

Tags: java, android, string, checkbox, arraylist

I am running into an issue in regards to adding/removing strings that have been added to an ArrayList everytime a checkbox is checked or unchecked.

The issue seems to be that the string is getting duplicated when more than 1 checkbox is checked. So if I was to check the 1st box, it would add it to the array. If I uncheck the first box it will remove it from the array. The issue arises when I do a second check box. When I press another checkbox it appears to add the previous checkboxes string, and than 2 of its current string.

```
Only the first checkbox checked 
10-29 14:46:10.051: E/PAGES(14154): [alertPage]

2 checkboxes checked
10-29 14:46:10.051: E/PAGES(14154): [alertPage, alertPage, automationPage]
```

and this pattern continues for each additional checkbox

**Any ideas as to why this is occurring?**

**strong text**

```
    if (mCheckBoxAlerts.isChecked()) {
        mAlertsPermLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
        pageArray.add("alertPage");
    } else {

        mAlertsPermLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
        pageArray.remove("alertPage");
    }
    if (mCheckBoxAutomation.isChecked()) {
        mAutomationPermLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
        pageArray.add("automationPage");
    } else {
        mAutomationPermLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
        pageArray.remove("automationPage");
    }
```

**Here is how I am converting to a string**

```
        String pageString = pageArray.toString();
        Log.e("PAGES", pageString);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you are adding another checkbox it is still checking to see if the previous checkbox is checked.  If it is it is adding another object same String to the arraylist.  You need to check if the arraylist already contains the string then don't add if it does.  I would recommend using a Set instead of an arraylist.  This will not allow duplicates where arraylist will.

Comment: Could try to use Hashmap for this as it will not allow duplicates to be added, but then again you can just check the array.

Comment: Yes Hashmap or Set would probably be better suited for this.  Set would probably be ideal for this Hashmap wouldn't really be great because you only need to store the String not key, value pair.